# How to define a constant in SML in a let binding way?

Tags: functional-programming, sml, ml, let

Is there a way to define a constant in SML in a let binding way.
So basically what I'm asking is how to for example do constant `x = 5`, in the way below:

```
let
   ....
in
   ...
end
```

Comment: Is there something wrong with `let x = 5 in ... end`? (All bindings are "constant" in SML.)

Answer (score 5):

Not sure I understand the question correctly, but

```
let val x = 5 in ... end
```

sounds like it did what you're asking for.